# How to *reopen* AsyncIterator after broke a "for await" loop?

Tags: javascript, async-iterator

In the function `testMultipleLoops2` after the first `for await`,
`l` will turn to `GeneratorStatus:<closed>`,
I've done huge research but didn't find a method to **reopen** it.

```js
const tryRecursive=async function*(i=0){console.count("tryRecursive");yield i++;yield*tryRecursive(i)}
const asyncDelay=(b,delay=1e3)=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(b()),delay))
const tryDelayYieldNumbers=async function*(){
  for await(const i of tryRecursive()){
    const result=await asyncDelay(()=>i)
    yield result}}
const testMultipleLoops2=(async()=>{
  const l=tryDelayYieldNumbers()
  let count=3
  for await(const i of l){if(count-->0)console.log(i);else break}
  count=4
  ///But `l` is closed here, can't do future looping
  for await(const i of l){if(count-->0)console.log(i);else break}
  count=5
  for await(const i of l){if(count-->0)console.log(i);else break}
})()
```

Comment: I see 0, 1, 2 ouptut to console - what do you see? what do you expect to see?

Comment: The expected o/p should like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11. @JaromandaX

Comment: The _desired_ output is `0, 1, 2, ... 11` - the _expected_ output is what you've got.

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! @Alnitak

Comment: @Alnitak - why is that expected :p

Comment: I need to loop it time&time again :D @Jaromanda X

Comment: I was talking to Alnitak not you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Closing_iterators

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is impossible.  By design (and per the language specification) your `iterator` variable `l` is "closed" at the end of the `for .. of` even if you terminate the loop early with a `break`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Closing_iterators

Comment: YES! That's the fact I saw, but if I use `while(true)` and `l.next().value`

Comment: I cant really loop it multiple time. I suspect it can be write in `for await` style.

Comment: Any time you use `for` on the iterator it's guaranteed that the iterator will no long be usable after that block.   That doesn't happen when you use `l.next()` because you're interacting directly with the iterator.